# Display a delivery day range based on shipping country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, country, shipping-method

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to add an estimated delivery day range on cart and checkout pages. 
I have set 2 shipping Zones: Germany and other European countries *(outside Germany)* called "DHL Europe". I need to display a different delivery day range for Germany shipping country than other European shipping countries:

- Germany shipping country will display "Lieferzeit **3-5** Werktage" *(and when there is no shipping costs)*.
- Other European shipping countries will display "Lieferzeit **5-7** Werktage"

My code attempt:

```
function sv_shipping_method_estimate_label( $label, $method ) {
    $label .= '<br /><small class="subtotal-tax">';
    switch ( $method->method_id ) {
        case 'flat_rate':
            $label .= 'Lieferzeit 3-5 Werktage';
            break;
        case 'free_shipping':
            $label .= 'Lieferzeit 3-5 Werktage';
            break;
        case 'international_delivery':
            $label .= 'Lieferzeit 5-7 Werktage';
    }

    $label .= '</small>';
    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'sv_shipping_method_estimate_label', 10, 2 );
```

It works with the `free_shipping` and `flat_rate` shipping methods, but not for European deliveries *(outside Germany)*.

What am I doing wrong? 
How to display the correct date range for European countries *(outside Germany)*?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($method->method_id);` before your `switch` and see if it really contains what you think it does/should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to target your shipping methods, but instead customer shipping country:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'cart_shipping_method_full_label_filter', 10, 2 );
function cart_shipping_method_full_label_filter( $label, $method ) {
    // The targeted country code
    $targeted_country_code = 'DE';

    if( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() !== $targeted_country_code ){
        $days_range = '5-7'; // International
    } else {
        $days_range = '3-5'; // Germany
    }
    return $label . '<br /><small class="subtotal-tax">' . sprintf( __("Lieferzeit %s Werktage"), $days_range ) . '</small>';
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thx for the help but with your code it's hiding the shipping label and the costs Before: https://s16.directupload.net/images/190321/e5x2hs4i.png  after https://s17.directupload.net/images/190321/dn6twqpi.png

Comment: made my day. Allways a pleasure